# Implementing abstract event gives "Invocation of polymorphic field-like event" warning from ReSharper

Tags: c#, events, resharper, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class with the following abstract event

```
public abstract class SignalWrapperBase<T> : IReadOnlySignal<T> {
  public abstract event Action<IReadOnlySignal<T>, Sample<T>> Updated;
  ...
}
```

in my implementation i simply say

```
public class ValueChangedSignal : SignalWrapperBase<T> {
  public override event Action<IReadOnlySignal<T>, Sample<T>> Updated;
  ...
}
```

and when I in the implementation `ValueChangedSignal` try to perform the following

```
if (Updated != null) { Updated(this, sample); }
```

I get a ReSharper warning: **Invocation of polymorphic field-like event**.

I checked the [reasoning](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Invocation+of+polymorphic+field-like+event) behind it, but it uses `virtual` not `abstract` in the example:

```
public class Base
{
  public virtual event EventHandler MyEvent;
}

public class Derived : Base
{
  public override event EventHandler MyEvent;
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    var args = ...;
    MyEvent(this, args);
  }
}
```

> The above block of code uses an overriding event declaration to override the implementation of the add and remove methods on an event. The field itself will then exist in two separate instances - one in Base and one in Derived. As a consequence, when working with Derived, you're likely to never instantiate the Base's MyEvent unless you explicitly set it to some value. And, as a result of that, the behavior in the case when the event is raised in the base class would differ from that in the derived class.

I get that I would get two instances if it were `virtual`. I would be hiding the base implementation with the actual implementation, however, when I use `abstract` I am never making a base implementation, am I? I thought that when I use abstract on some field I am simply forwarding the implementation to the inheriting class, i.e., I am requiring the user of my base class to implement the abstract code.

Is ReSharper giving me a wrong warning? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I wonder why you make the event abstract in the first place. Wouldn't the suggested resolution work in your scenario? To answer your question: It looks like a false warning on ReSharper's behalf.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks for the comment. To answer your question. I made it abstract because I want the author of a new SignalWrapper to be perfectly aware that the event exists so that (s)he remembers to actually to supply it with events. It makes the code more readable. Of course this information could be added as a comment, and it will, but this is an extra safe guard.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. Why would an author of a new `SignalWrapper` need to supply events (I suppose you mean *event handlers* here?)? This is the job of the *consumer* / *client* of the new `SignalWrapper`.

Comment: A `SignalWrapper` is simply an event filter. It selects which events it wants to pass along and will thus have to invoke the `Updated` event whenever it receives an event with certain criteria. It might also be that I am misusing the conceptual language.

Comment: I am aware that this really wasn't your question, so if you aren't interested in discussing your design decision, just say so. However, if you are interested: How does it receive the event?

Comment: I guess I should listen, I don't want to make some rookie mistake. I inject an `IReadOnlySignal` into the wrapper, then in the constructor subscribe my `OnUpdated` method to its `Update` event. In the `OnUpdated` method I invoke the wrapper's `Update` event given that some criteria is fulfilled. Thus if anybody subscribes to the wrapper's `Update` event and not the injected `IReadOnlySignal` it gets a filtered version of the events. To me it makes sense. If you really think I am making a mistake I'll bring in a senior developer, but I think I am at the limit of what I can say online.

Comment: That sounds perfectly reasonable. But I don't see why you would need an abstract event in such a scenario (or most other scenarios for that matter). It only complicates things. It doesn't communicate. The whole purpose of a `SignalWrapper` seems to be to (a) listen to event on decorated instance and (b) raise event if some filter criteria is fulfilled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33493/discussion-between-andre-christoffer-andersen-and-daniel-hilgarth)

Comment: It should be enough to just declare the overridden event `sealed`. That is `public override sealed event Action<IReadOnlySignal<T>, Sample<T>> Updated;`. In that case there can be no trouble with classes deriving further from `Derived`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a false warning and Resharper puts your attention on fact that **your derived class can be inherited as well and event overridden**.

Let's see an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base b = new Derived();

        b.E += (sender, eventArgs) => { Console.WriteLine("Event Handled"); };
        b.Raise();
    }

    abstract class Base
    {
        public abstract event EventHandler E;
        public abstract void Raise();
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public override event EventHandler E;
        public override void Raise()
        {
            if (E != null)
                E(this, null); // Resharper: Invocation of polymorphic field-like events
        }
    }
```

Result of Main(): *Event Handled*

Everything works as expected: we subscribed to event E, raised event E and can see message from the event subscribtion on the screen.

Now, if we inherit another class from DerivedClass and override event like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base b = new MostDerived();

        b.E += (sender, eventArgs) => { Console.WriteLine("Event Handled"); };
        b.Raise();
    }

    class MostDerived : Derived
    {
        public override event EventHandler E;
    }
```

things change and now Main() puts out *nothing*.

It happens because there is two private fields of event E in object *b*: one comes from Derived class and the other from MostDerived. That's exactly what Resharper warned about.

If you're sure Derived class will never be inherited and event E overriden, mark Derived as **sealed** and Resharper warning will disappear.

Comment: It should not be necessary to declare the entire class `Derived` sealed. Just make the event sealed. So `public override sealed event EventHandler E;` inside class `Derived`. Then a class `MostDerived : Derived` can be written, but you cannot specialize (override) `E`. Will ReSharper acknowledge?